# Module in django

Tags: django, module, pycharm

this error comes to me when i try to makemigrations in cmd:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'homsapp.app'

virtualenv_name: repro
project_name: homspro
app_name:homsapp

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class location(models.Module):
        location_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
        location_type=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class propertyview(models.Model):
        location = models.ForeignKey(location,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        property_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        property_area=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

installed _apps in setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'homsapp.app.HomsappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

it's `apps` and NOT `app`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'homsapp.apps.HomsappConfig',
    ..
]
```

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#for-application-users

## Update

as **@Alasdair** stated in comments below, you've made a typo in this line

```
class location(models.Module):
```

it's `Model` and NOT `Module`

```
class location(models.Model):
```

and as good coding practices, it's recommended to capitalize your models' names since they are after all a classes, i.e. `Location` and `PropertyView`

Comment: still not work , i wrote :  python manage.py makemigrations homsapp , this error comes:      AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Module'

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'homsapp.apps.HomsappConfig',.......

Comment: The `Module` error is a different issue, it should be `class location(models.Model):`. Note they the recommendation is to capitalise your model names, i.e. `Location` and `PropertyView`.

Answer (score 0):

from django.db import models

class location(models.Model):